# How to use Google APIs in flutter without authentication, only using api key?

Tags: flutter, google-api

How to use Google APIs in flutter without authentication, i.e. only using api key.

For example:

```dart
const _myApiKey = '...';

final client = Client();
final youTubeApi = YouTubeApi(client);
final searchList = await youTubeApi.search.list(['snippet'], maxResults: 25, q: 'flutter');
```

Where to use the `_myApiKey`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [googleapis_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis_auth) package to your project
2. Use the function `clientViaApiKey` to obtain a `Client`, and use it instead of the one you usually obtain using google sign-in authentication:

```dart
import 'package:googleapis/places/v1.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/googleapis_auth.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> main() async {
  // this is to make the code compile, but the package needs
  // me to authenticate using google sign in to get a valid client
  http.Client client = clientViaApiKey('YOUR_API_KEY');

  PlacesApi placesApi = PlacesApi(client);
  PlacesResource placesResource = placesApi.places;
  var result = await placesResource.searchText(
    GoogleMapsPlacesV1SearchTextRequest(
      textQuery: 'resturants in nairobi'
    ),
  );
  print(result);
}
```